# How do I get python Parallel to work with local mysql server?

Tags: python, mysql, parallel-processing

I'm attempting to parallelize a bunch of inserts to mysql. All the db server settings look ready for lots of connections and/or threads. Full code and full error message added below.
Googling the final error message didn't return anything relevant:

> OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

```
Code:
> #!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# price_retrieval.py

from __future__ import print_function

import datetime
import warnings

import MySQLdb as mdb
import requests
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

# Obtain a database connection to the MySQL instance
db_host = 'localhost'
db_user = 'sec_user'
db_pass = 'password'
db_name = 'securities_master'
con = mdb.connect(db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name)


def obtain_list_of_db_tickers():
   """
   Obtains a list of the ticker symbols in the database.
   """
   with con:
       cur = con.cursor()
       cur.execute("SELECT id, ticker FROM symbol")
       data = cur.fetchall()
       return [(d[0], d[1]) for d in data]


def is_db_current():
   # check that database is loaded up to yesterday's details or the last trading day.
   # ??? is there an app for last trading day. # holidays could trip up schedule.
   # nothing is currently designed for same day data.
   sql = "select max(price_date), symbol_id, ticker \
       from securities_master.daily_price left join securities_master.symbol \
       on  securities_master.daily_price.symbol_id =  securities_master.symbol.id \
       group by symbol_id limit 5"
#
   today = datetime.date.today().weekday()
   data = None
   with con:
       cur = con.cursor()
       cur.execute(sql)
       data = cur.fetchall()
   tuples = [(d[0], d[1], d[2]) for d in data]

   # if data is upto yesterday return true
   # elsif data is current up to friday return true
   # so if friday is filled and it's sat or sun or mon return true.
   # Monday = 0 Sunday = 6
   for t in tuples:
       if abs(today - t[0].weekday()) <= 1:
           #good but keep looping.
           continue
       elif today in [5,6,0]  and t[0].weekday() == 4:
           #good but keey looping.
           continue
       else:
           return False
       # made it through checks so
   return True
#        datetime.utcnow().dayofweek

def get_daily_historic_data_yahoo(
       ticker, start_date=(2000,1,1),
       end_date=datetime.date.today().timetuple()[0:3]
   ):
   """
   Obtains data from Yahoo Finance returns and a list of tuples.

   ticker: Yahoo Finance ticker symbol, e.g. "GOOG" for Google, Inc.
   start_date: Start date in (YYYY, M, D) format
   end_date: End date in (YYYY, M, D) format
   """
   # Construct the Yahoo URL with the correct integer query parameters
   # for start and end dates. Note that some parameters are zero-based!
   ticker_tup = (
       ticker, start_date[1]-1, start_date[2],
       start_date[0], end_date[1]-1, end_date[2],
       end_date[0]
   )
   yahoo_url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv"
   yahoo_url += "?s=%s&a=%s&b=%s&c=%s&d=%s&e=%s&f=%s"
   yahoo_url = yahoo_url % ticker_tup

   # Try connecting to Yahoo Finance and obtaining the data
   # On failure, print an error message.
   try:
       yf_data = requests.get(yahoo_url).text.split("\n")[1:-1]
       prices = []
       for y in yf_data:
           p = y.strip().split(',')
           prices.append(
               (datetime.datetime.strptime(p[0], '%Y-%m-%d'),
               p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5], p[6])
           )
   except Exception as e:
       print("Could not download Yahoo data: %s" % e)
   return prices

def get_daily_historid_data_google():
   prices = []
   return prices

def insert_daily_data_into_db(
       data_vendor_id, symbol_id, daily_data
   ):
   """
   Takes a list of tuples of daily data and adds it to the
   MySQL database. Appends the vendor ID and symbol ID to the data.

   daily_data: List of tuples of the OHLC data (with
   adj_close and volume)
   """
   # Create the time now
   now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

   # Amend the data to include the vendor ID and symbol ID
   daily_data = [
       (data_vendor_id, symbol_id, d[0], now, now,
       d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5], d[6])
       for d in daily_data
   ]

   # Create the insert strings
   column_str = """data_vendor_id, symbol_id, price_date, created_date,
                last_updated_date, open_price, high_price, low_price,
                close_price, volume, adj_close_price"""
   insert_str = ("%s, " * 11)[:-2]
   final_str = "INSERT IGNORE INTO daily_price (%s) VALUES (%s)" % \
       (column_str, insert_str)

   # Using the MySQL connection, carry out an INSERT INTO for every symbol
   with con:
       cur = con.cursor()
       cur.executemany(final_str, daily_data)

def load_ticker_history(t):
   print( "Adding data for %s" % (t[1]) )
   yf_data = get_daily_historic_data_yahoo(t[1], (2015,01,01))
   insert_daily_data_into_db('1', t[0], yf_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   # This ignores the warnings regarding Data Truncation
   # from the Yahoo precision to Decimal(19,4) datatypes
   warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

   # Loop over the tickers and insert the daily historical
   # data into the database
   tickers = obtain_list_of_db_tickers()
   lentickers = len(tickers)
   num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
   print("numCores = " + str(num_cores))

   if is_db_current():
       print("db current: True")
   else:
       # not sure why
       Parallel(n_jobs=1)(delayed(load_ticker_history)(t) for t in tickers)
       print("Successfully added Yahoo Finance pricing data to DB.")
```

Error

> Output:
>
> /usr/bin/python
>   /Users/darianhickman/Documents/Quantstart/src/dev/price_retrieval.py
>   numCores = 2 Adding data for A Adding data for AA Adding data for AAL
>   Adding data for AAP Adding data for AAPL Adding data for ABBV Adding
>   data for ABC Adding data for ABT Adding data for ACE Adding data for
>   ACN Adding data for ADBE Adding data for ADI Adding data for ADM
>   Adding data for ADP Adding data for ADS Adding data for ADSK Adding
>   data for ADT Adding data for AEE Adding data for AEP Adding data for
>   AES Adding data for AET Adding data for AFL Adding data for AGN Adding
>   data for AIG Adding data for AIV Adding data for AIZ Adding data for
>   AKAM Adding data for ALL Adding data for ALLE Adding data for ALTR
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/darianhickman/Documents/Quantstart/src/dev/price_retrieval.py",
>   line 164, in 
>       Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(load_ticker_history)(t) for t in tickers)   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 660, in
>   **call**
>       self.retrieve()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 543, in
>   retrieve
>       raise exception_type(report) joblib.my_exceptions.JoblibOperationalError: JoblibOperationalError
>   ___________________________________________________________________________ Multiprocessing exception:
>       ...........................................................................
>   /Users/darianhickman/Documents/Quantstart/src/dev/price_retrieval.py
>   in ()
>       159     print("numCores = " + str(num_cores))
>       160 
>       161     if not is_db_current():
>       162         print("db current: True")
>       163     else:
>   --> 164         Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(load_ticker_history)(t) for t in tickers)
>       165         print("Successfully added Yahoo Finance pricing data to DB.")
>       166 
>       167 
>       168
>
> ...........................................................................
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in
>   **call**(self=Parallel(n_jobs=2), iterable=>)
>       655             if pre_dispatch == "all" or n_jobs == 1:
>       656                 # The iterable was consumed all at once by the above for loop.
>       657                 # No need to wait for async callbacks to trigger to
>       658                 # consumption.
>       659                 self._iterating = False
>   --> 660             self.retrieve()
>           self.retrieve = 
>       661             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
>       662             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time
>       663             self._print('Done %3i out of %3i | elapsed: %s finished',
>       664                         (len(self._output),
>
> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Sub-process traceback:
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> OperationalError                                   Fri Sep 11 22:42:58 2015 PID: 39551                                   Python
> ```
>
> 2.7.10: /usr/bin/python ...........................................................................
>   /Users/darianhickman/Documents/Quantstart/src/dev/price_retrieval.py
>   in load_ticker_history(t=(17L, 'AKAM'))
>       141         cur.executemany(final_str, daily_data)
>       142 
>       143 def load_ticker_history(t):
>       144     print( "Adding data for %s" % (t[1]) )
>       145     yf_data = get_daily_historic_data_yahoo(t[1], (2015,01,01))
>   --> 146     insert_daily_data_into_db('1', t[0], yf_data)
>           t = (17L, 'AKAM')
>           yf_data = [(datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 11, 0, 0), u'74.32', u'75.32', u'73.940002', u'74.669998', u'1368400', u'74.669998'),
>   (datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 10, 0, 0), u'73.279999', u'75.029999',
>   u'73.190002', u'74.550003', u'1408900', u'74.550003'),
>   (datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 9, 0, 0), u'74.879997', u'75.25',
>   u'73.129997', u'73.349998', u'1273300', u'73.349998'),
>   (datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 8, 0, 0), u'73.75', u'74.349998',
>   u'73.059998', u'74.279999', u'1413600', u'74.279999'),
>   (datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 4, 0, 0), u'71.709999', u'73.169998',
>   u'71.709999', u'72.580002', u'1607100', u'72.580002'),
>   (datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 3, 0, 0), u'71.860001', u'74.709999',
>   u'71.540001', u'73.260002', u'2378600', u'73.260002'),
>   (datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 2, 0, 0), u'71.349998', u'71.669998',
>   u'69.669998', u'71.269997', u'1671900', u'71.269997'),
>   (datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 1, 0, 0), u'69.75', u'71.43',
>   u'69.669998', u'70.43', u'2401800', u'70.43'),
>   (datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 31, 0, 0), u'71.660004', u'71.809998',
>   u'70.870003', u'71.309998', u'1764400', u'71.309998'),
>   (datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 28, 0, 0), u'70.589996', u'71.970001',
>   u'70.199997', u'71.900002', u'2371800', u'71.900002'),
>   (datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 27, 0, 0), u'69.089996', u'70.889999',
>   u'68.529999', u'70.50', u'2081800', u'70.50'),
>   (datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 26, 0, 0), u'67.07', u'68.300003',
>   u'65.330002', u'68.169998', u'2238400', u'68.169998'),
>   (datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 25, 0, 0), u'68.239998', u'68.989998',
>   u'65.589996', u'65.629997', u'3112100', u'65.629997'),
>   (datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 24, 0, 0), u'65.010002', u'68.220001',
>   u'63.139999', u'66.519997', u'3779300', u'66.519997'),
>   (datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 21, 0, 0), u'69.190002', u'70.00',
>   u'67.910004', u'68.040001', u'2298300', u'68.040001'),
>   (datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 20, 0, 0), u'72.300003', u'72.57',
>   u'69.769997', u'69.779999', u'2096000', u'69.779999'),
>   (datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 19, 0, 0), u'73.779999', u'73.900002',
>   u'72.290001', u'73.059998', u'881700', u'73.059998'),
>   (datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 18, 0, 0), u'73.959999', u'74.190002',
>   u'73.230003', u'73.849998', u'1220500', u'73.849998'),
>   (datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 17, 0, 0), u'73.010002', u'73.599998',
>   u'72.32', u'73.57', u'1025600', u'73.57'), (datetime.datetime(2015, 8,
>   14, 0, 0), u'73.379997', u'73.839996', u'72.730003', u'73.370003',
>   u'1328400', u'73.370003'), ...]
>       147 
>       148 
>       149 if **name** == "**main**":
>       150     # This ignores the warnings regarding Data Truncation
>
> ...........................................................................
>   /Users/darianhickman/Documents/Quantstart/src/dev/price_retrieval.py
>   in insert_daily_data_into_db(data_vendor_id='1', symbol_id=17L,
>   daily_data=[('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 11, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'74.32', u'75.32',
>   u'73.940002', u'74.669998', u'1368400', u'74.669998'), ('1', 17L,
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12,
>   2, 42, 58, 361925), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   u'73.279999', u'75.029999', u'73.190002', u'74.550003', u'1408900',
>   u'74.550003'), ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 9, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'74.879997',
>   u'75.25', u'73.129997', u'73.349998', u'1273300', u'73.349998'), ('1',
>   17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9,
>   12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58,
>   361925), u'73.75', u'74.349998', u'73.059998', u'74.279999',
>   u'1413600', u'74.279999'), ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 4, 0,
>   0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'71.709999',
>   u'73.169998', u'71.709999', u'72.580002', u'1607100', u'72.580002'),
>   ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 3, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'71.860001',
>   u'74.709999', u'71.540001', u'73.260002', u'2378600', u'73.260002'),
>   ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 2, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'71.349998',
>   u'71.669998', u'69.669998', u'71.269997', u'1671900', u'71.269997'),
>   ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 1, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'69.75', u'71.43',
>   u'69.669998', u'70.43', u'2401800', u'70.43'), ('1', 17L,
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12,
>   2, 42, 58, 361925), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   u'71.660004', u'71.809998', u'70.870003', u'71.309998', u'1764400',
>   u'71.309998'), ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 28, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'70.589996',
>   u'71.970001', u'70.199997', u'71.900002', u'2371800', u'71.900002'),
>   ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 27, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'69.089996',
>   u'70.889999', u'68.529999', u'70.50', u'2081800', u'70.50'), ('1',
>   17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9,
>   12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58,
>   361925), u'67.07', u'68.300003', u'65.330002', u'68.169998',
>   u'2238400', u'68.169998'), ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 25,
>   0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'68.239998',
>   u'68.989998', u'65.589996', u'65.629997', u'3112100', u'65.629997'),
>   ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 24, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'65.010002',
>   u'68.220001', u'63.139999', u'66.519997', u'3779300', u'66.519997'),
>   ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 21, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'69.190002',
>   u'70.00', u'67.910004', u'68.040001', u'2298300', u'68.040001'), ('1',
>   17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 20, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9,
>   12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58,
>   361925), u'72.300003', u'72.57', u'69.769997', u'69.779999',
>   u'2096000', u'69.779999'), ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 19,
>   0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'73.779999',
>   u'73.900002', u'72.290001', u'73.059998', u'881700', u'73.059998'),
>   ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 18, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'73.959999',
>   u'74.190002', u'73.230003', u'73.849998', u'1220500', u'73.849998'),
>   ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 17, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'73.010002',
>   u'73.599998', u'72.32', u'73.57', u'1025600', u'73.57'), ('1', 17L,
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12,
>   2, 42, 58, 361925), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   u'73.379997', u'73.839996', u'72.730003', u'73.370003', u'1328400',
>   u'73.370003'), ...])
>       136         (column_str, insert_str)
>       137 
>       138     # Using the MySQL connection, carry out an INSERT INTO for every symbol
>       139     with con: 
>       140         cur = con.cursor()
>   --> 141         cur.executemany(final_str, daily_data)
>           cur.executemany = >
>           final_str = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO daily_price (data_vendor_id, ...LUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
>           daily_data = [('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 11, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'74.32', u'75.32',
>   u'73.940002', u'74.669998', u'1368400', u'74.669998'), ('1', 17L,
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12,
>   2, 42, 58, 361925), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   u'73.279999', u'75.029999', u'73.190002', u'74.550003', u'1408900',
>   u'74.550003'), ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 9, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'74.879997',
>   u'75.25', u'73.129997', u'73.349998', u'1273300', u'73.349998'), ('1',
>   17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9,
>   12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58,
>   361925), u'73.75', u'74.349998', u'73.059998', u'74.279999',
>   u'1413600', u'74.279999'), ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 4, 0,
>   0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'71.709999',
>   u'73.169998', u'71.709999', u'72.580002', u'1607100', u'72.580002'),
>   ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 3, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'71.860001',
>   u'74.709999', u'71.540001', u'73.260002', u'2378600', u'73.260002'),
>   ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 2, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'71.349998',
>   u'71.669998', u'69.669998', u'71.269997', u'1671900', u'71.269997'),
>   ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 1, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'69.75', u'71.43',
>   u'69.669998', u'70.43', u'2401800', u'70.43'), ('1', 17L,
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12,
>   2, 42, 58, 361925), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   u'71.660004', u'71.809998', u'70.870003', u'71.309998', u'1764400',
>   u'71.309998'), ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 28, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'70.589996',
>   u'71.970001', u'70.199997', u'71.900002', u'2371800', u'71.900002'),
>   ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 27, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'69.089996',
>   u'70.889999', u'68.529999', u'70.50', u'2081800', u'70.50'), ('1',
>   17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9,
>   12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58,
>   361925), u'67.07', u'68.300003', u'65.330002', u'68.169998',
>   u'2238400', u'68.169998'), ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 25,
>   0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'68.239998',
>   u'68.989998', u'65.589996', u'65.629997', u'3112100', u'65.629997'),
>   ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 24, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'65.010002',
>   u'68.220001', u'63.139999', u'66.519997', u'3779300', u'66.519997'),
>   ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 21, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'69.190002',
>   u'70.00', u'67.910004', u'68.040001', u'2298300', u'68.040001'), ('1',
>   17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 20, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9,
>   12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58,
>   361925), u'72.300003', u'72.57', u'69.769997', u'69.779999',
>   u'2096000', u'69.779999'), ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 19,
>   0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'73.779999',
>   u'73.900002', u'72.290001', u'73.059998', u'881700', u'73.059998'),
>   ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 18, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'73.959999',
>   u'74.190002', u'73.230003', u'73.849998', u'1220500', u'73.849998'),
>   ('1', 17L, datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 17, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925), u'73.010002',
>   u'73.599998', u'72.32', u'73.57', u'1025600', u'73.57'), ('1', 17L,
>   datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12,
>   2, 42, 58, 361925), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 12, 2, 42, 58, 361925),
>   u'73.379997', u'73.839996', u'72.730003', u'73.370003', u'1328400',
>   u'73.370003'), ...]
>       142 
>       143 def load_ticker_history(t):
>       144     print( "Adding data for %s" % (t[1]) )
>       145     yf_data = get_daily_historic_data_yahoo(t[1], (2015,01,01))
>
> ...........................................................................
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.pyc in
>   **exit**(self=<_mysql.connection open to 'localhost' at 7fb5930b1a20>, exc=,
>   value=OperationalError(2006, 'MySQL server has gone away'),
>   tb=)
>       258             self.query("BEGIN")
>       259         return self.cursor()
>       260 
>       261     def **exit**(self, exc, value, tb):
>       262         if exc:
>   --> 263             self.rollback()
>       264         else:
>       265             self.commit()
>       266 
>       267     def literal(self, o):
>
> OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
>
> ---
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: has gone away indicates a period of inactivity after which the daemon closes the connection, perhaps even a pool manager

Comment: Yeah that's why the error is super annoying... there's definitely not inactivity when I try to open 8 threads to and push.  It's a consisting error even when I i've just tested connectivity with workbench.  I noticed the error takes a few seconds longer to happen when I do 2 threads instead of 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL connections are not thread safe. This error can occur when you have multiple processes attempting to use the same connection.

Ensure that each parallel process creates and destroys its own connection to the database.

From the MySQL documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gone-away.html):

> You can also encounter this error with applications that fork child processes, all of which try to use the same connection to the MySQL server. This can be avoided by using a separate connection for each child process.

Comment: That worked I did it the dumb way and put the connection creation the function that does a mysql insert for every ticker symbol.   I guess a 2.0 will create a bucket of connections one per core and round robin the execution on them.  Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(load_ticker_history)(t) for t in tickers) and put     con = mdb.connect(db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name)
inside load_ticker_history(t)

Comment: Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(load_ticker_history)(t) for t in tickers) and put

Answer (score 0):

You should create a connection pool instead of sharing the same connection among threads. You can almost effortlessly (with addition of 1 or 2 parameters to your connect statement) do that using something like:

```
dbconfig = {
  "database": "test",
  "user":     "joe"
}

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(pool_name = "mypool",
                              pool_size = 3,
                              **dbconfig)
```

Note in this snippet you're implicitly creating a connection pool. You can also create it explicitly using:

```
dbconfig = {
  "database": "test",
  "user":     "joe"
}

cnxpool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name = "mypool",
                                                      pool_size = 3,
                                                      **dbconfig)
```

And then:

```
cnx1 = cnxpool.get_connection()
cnx2 = cnxpool.get_connection()
```

[Read more here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html).